# Use custom async targets with NLog and dependency inject HttpClient

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, nlog

I am using a [custom async target](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-write-a-custom-async-target) that writes logs to Splunk with NLog (5.0.1.) in my .NET 6 application. I want to leverage [IHttpClientFactory in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-5.0#basic-usage).

In my *startup.cs*, under *ConfigureServices(),* I register my new target and NLog configuration file.

```
Target.Register<SplunkTarget>("Splunk");
LogManager.LoadConfiguration("NLog.config");
```

When I try to inject the `IHttpClientFactory` into my target class's instructor like this:

```
private readonly IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory;
public SplunkTarget(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
{
     _clientFactory = clientFactory;
}
```

I'm unable to start the application because I get the error:

> Exception thrown: 'System.MissingMethodException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll: 'Cannot dynamically create an instance of type 'MyNamespace.SplunkTarget'. Reason: No parameterless constructor defined.'

How do I use the built-in .NET Core *HttpFactory* so that I don't have to manually create a `Httpclient`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With NLog 5.0 then you can resolve dependencies during initialization:

```
public class MyCustomTarget : AsyncTaskTarget
{
    protected override void InitializeTarget()
    {
        // ResolveService will throw if dependency is not available,
        // and target-initialization will retry when dependency is available
        var clientFactory = ResolveService<IHttpClientFactory>();
    }
}
```

If the target must work at startup, then you must register the singleton-interface upfront:

```
NLog.LogManager.Setup().SetupExtensions(ext => ext.RegisterSingletonService<IHttpClientFactory>(clientFactory));
```

But you are also allowed to post-pone the registration until `UseNLog()` or `AddNLog()` are called, and the Microsoft ServiceProvider is registered as external dependency-injection-provider (All LogEvents generated until that point will be cached and released on target-initialization success).

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Dependency-injection-with-NLog

P.S. Before NLog 5.0 then one could override the factory-method like this, and perform the dependency injection:

```
var defaultConstructor = ConfigurationItemFactory.Default.CreateInstance;

ConfigurationItemFactory.Default.CreateInstance.CreateInstance = type =>
{
   if (type == typeof(MyCustomTarget))
       return new MyCustomTarget(myCustomParameter);
   
   return defaultConstructor(type);
};
```

Comment: I'm using NLog 5.0.1. ResolveService threw error "Cannot resolve the type: 'IHttpClientFactory'. Instance of class must be registered.' If I use RegisterSingletonService, is that supposed to be in the custom target class or is that done at startup?

Comment: Yes you need to call `RegisterSingletonService` before loading the NLog-configuration, if you want to avoid the error about not resolving type at first initialization attempt. But notice NLog will automatically retry target-initialization of your custom target, when detecting the required dependency becomes available (Ex. from `AddNLog` or `UseNLog`)

Comment: @duyn9uyen If you have ideas for how improve or simplify the use of dependency injection with `ResolveService<IHttpClientFactory>()` then please tell.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Rolf Kristensen's answer and this [link](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Dependency-injection-with-NLog), I ended up doing this.

In my *startup.cs,* under *ConfigureServices()*:

```
services.AddHttpClient(); // plus all other needed services for DI

// Build the intermediate service provider so that we can pass this to NLog for DI. 
// Note that all needed services need to be added before this
var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();
NLog.LogManager.Setup().SetupExtensions(ext => ext.RegisterServiceProvider(sp));


// I register my new target and NLog configuration file.
Target.Register<SplunkTarget>("Splunk");
LogManager.LoadConfiguration("NLog.config");
```

Then in my target class:

```
protected override void InitializeTarget()
{
    _httpClientFactory = base.ResolveService<IHttpClientFactory>();
    base.InitializeTarget();
}
```